# At what frequency do you send user interaction data to the server?

Tags: java, android

Lets consider Tinder, where users can like/dislike other persons. A user session can consist out of 0 likes/dislikes or 100s of them. I was wondering when and how do you send this like/dislike data to the server? I thought of some ways to do it but i would like to have some experts opinion on this topic.

1. An webservice call for every like/dislike (inefficient, and resource consuming)
2. Grouping the calls per 10-50 like/dislike or when the user exits the app.
3. Sending all when the user exists (No internet?, retry?)

I have some experience in java/android but i would like to know more on this topic, thanks in advance!

Comment: As a user, in case the phone runs out of battery while your app is running, I wouldn't want my actions to be lost. Thus I would advocate for point 1.

Comment: @wiz3kid You can persist requests to disk and then batch requests up to send.

Comment: Ahh, then wait for an answer.

Comment: An addition to #2 could be to never wait more than x minutes before sending. So you batch until the oldest action is x minutes old or the queue contains y actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It always depends on what you're looking to achieve really. Though considering Tinder I'd probably go with option 2.

You could have a pool of say 10 people you can like/dislike (from hereon action). In order for the user to recieve realtime feedback of a possible match you'd include a flag when the other person has already liked the user. Now, for every action the user performs you'd store it locally in a queue of sorts.

Once the user has exhausted his pool, or the user exits the app, all actions stored in the queue can be offloaded to the server. How you clean out the queue depends on you really, you could empty it the moment you start sending the actions to the server, or can do this after your server has sent a reply. I'd recommend the latter as this will also allow you to resend if anything goes wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your response, currentyly i am thinking of doing it in an unbound service which is run after 10 entries or on exit. If succeded the likes/dislikes are removed from local storage, if not it will try again at next startup.